# I cant find the page which is I know permalink in wordpress for editing

Tags: wordpress

I know the permalink: "mysite.com/2017".
But I can't find the page in WordPress.

I create a page. And I was given the permalink "mysite.com/2017" to this page. But WordPress automatically change the permalink to "mysite.com/2017-2"

I used a plugin called [List all URLs](https://wordpress.org/plugins/list-all-urls/). But plugin not showed "mysite.com/2017". The page exists but I can't find in WordPress.

My Questions:

- Can I force the WordPress for the change the new page permalink to
  "mysite.com/2017"?
- Or How can find the page "mysite.com/2017" in WordPress for editing
  permalink?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you had another version with the same name before, so Wordpress renamed the page slug to "2017-2".

But when you edit the page (calling it from the "All Pages" list in the backend), below the title and next to the permalink there, you can click the "Edit" button to change the permalink of that page to whatever you like.